# PCIe Ethernet Controller that works with 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, networking, pcie

It appears that an awry cable has damaged both of the Ethernet ports (left most pin) on my $600 motherboard. Furious.

Are there any PCI-express NIC brands that will work well on Ubuntu out of the box? Meaning, without having to mess with drivers etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical have put out a list of certified hardware for Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10 & 11.04

This also includes [network cards](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/NETWORK).  Have a look through this list for PCI-Express cards to find one that fits your budget and requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find such a site but I guess I didn't look hard enough.